# Using Json data with React state. Not able to get the right data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an (SharePoint Framework) react example using a rest call. Working fine.
This is the most important piece of code:

```
    export interface IReactGetItemsState{  
    items:[  
    {  
      "EmployeeName": "",  
      "EmployeeId": "",  
      "Experience":"",  
      "Location":""
    }]  
  }  

  export default class ReactGetItems extends React.Component<IReactGetItemsProps, IReactGetItemsState> {

public constructor(props: IReactGetItemsProps, state: IReactGetItemsState){  
  super(props);  
  this.state = {  
    items: [  
      {  
        "EmployeeName": "",  
        "EmployeeId": "",  
        "Experience":"",  
        "Location":""
      }  
    ]  
  };  
}  

public componentDidMount(){
   var reactHandler = this;
   jquery.ajax({
   url: `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeList')/items`,
   type: "GET",
   headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},
   success: function(resultData) {
   reactHandler.setState({
   items: resultData.d.results
   });
   },
   error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   }
   });
   }

   public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactGetItemsProps> {
    return (  

       <div className={styles.panelStyle} > 
         <br></br>

         <br></br> 
         <div className={styles.tableCaptionStyle} > Demo : Retrieve SharePoint List Items using SPFx , REST API  & React JS  </div>
         <br></br>
          <div className={styles.headerCaptionStyle} > Employee Details</div>
         <div className={styles.tableStyle} >   

           <div className={styles.headerStyle} >  
             <div className={styles.CellStyle}>Employee Name</div>  
             <div className={styles.CellStyle}>Employee Id </div>  
             <div className={styles.CellStyle}>Experience</div>  
               <div className={styles.CellStyle}>Location</div>  

           </div>  
            {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){  

               return (<div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}>  
                   <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.EmployeeName}     </div>  
                   <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.EmployeeId}</div>  
                    <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Experience}</div>
                     <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Location}</div>

                 </div>);  
             })}  

         </div>  
       </div>
```

So "items: resultData.d.results" maps my json result to "items"

Now I try to do the same but my json has some other format so "items: resultData.d.results" is not working.

In my normal javascript code I would do a for loop to populate an Array to store my data. Like this "var someArray = results[i].Cells.results[2].Value;"

I have no idea how to achieve the same using react (I'm very new using that).

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? do you get any errors? react uses javascript so why do you think you can't use a regular for loop?

Comment: I do not get any data, for example,. "item.EmployeeName" is empty. I try to keep with the current structure. Also to learn some React.

Comment: are you waiting to make sure the ajax response is received before accessing the data?

Comment: React is trying to access the data before it has come back from the API - add a check before accessing the data, something like `results.length > 0 && doSomethingHere`.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the structure of the Json is different. So I cannot "map" a "piece" of jason to "items". I think, I need to create it.

Comment: Why are you using JQuery with react?

Comment: Did not really think about it. Copied it from the example

Comment: The core question is. How do I get data which is here "resultData.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results.Cells.results" in "items"?

Comment: @hacking_mike I think you should learn react via the website's documentation. And also, you don't have to use multiple DOM manipulating tools at a time and often it'll cause more harm than good.

Comment: I agree but I just wanted this example running and learn from that. I'm really close.